# How do I open a file with Chrome from the command line?

Tags: bash, google-chrome

I would like to open a file (index.html) in the current directory with Google Chrome or Chromium from a bash terminal (I'm using Linux Mint 15).  What is the command?  I've tried the intuitive approaches and have done a few stack and google searches to no avail, oddly overlooked (perhaps painfully obvious).

```
hermes@hades ~/coding/.../public $ google-chrome index.html
google-chrome: command not found
hermes@hades ~/coding/.../public $ google-chromium index.html
google-chromium: command not found
```

Comment: if chrome is set as your default browser, just `open index.html`. Otherwise, `open -a (chrome location) index.html`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer at least on a Mac.

Comment: @chovy Unfortunately it's not about Mac.

Comment: related: for those trying to install chromium for lighthouse purposes, have to install chromium (v7) instead of chromium-browser (v6)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doing some search for chromium you could do it like `chromium-browser path|file`.

Comment: `$ chromium-browser
-bash: chromium-browser: command not found`

Comment: @chovy It probably means you don't have `chromium-browser`.

Answer (score 69):

Just type in the program name followed by the file:

```
google-chrome {file-path}
```

ex:

```
google-chrome ~/index.html
```

Comment: this does not work for me... I'll edit the above with terminal output

Comment: ok. We need to find which chrome you have. CD to `/usr/bin` and do a ` `find . -name *chrome*` if you dont get anything, try `find . -name *chromium*` let me know what you get.

Comment: google-chrome is not in /usr/bin and neither is chromium

Comment: @neaumusic did you try `find / -name *chrom*`? Do you have either installed?

Comment: @NickHumrich is `google-chrome` or `chromium` a separate package that you have to install? definitely do not see any command/alias, but `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app` seems to work

Comment: @neaumusic yes, you have to install chrome first. Looks like you have a mac. If you set chrome as your default, all you need to do is `open {file}`

Answer (score 52):

Try

```
 open {filename}
```

if it's an `.html` file it should open in your default browser

Comment: A cross-platform way to do this would be `python -m webbrowser {filename}`. For linux, `xdg-open {filename}` will typically work. But again, that only works if chrome is set as the default application for that filetype.

Comment: This worked nicely for mac osx xml files with chrome as default browser

Comment: Make sure your default app is Chrome to use this way, I need to change it from default XCODE following the steps below: 

1. On your Mac, click the Finder icon in the Dock to open a Finder window.
2. Select the file, then choose File > Get Info. ...
3. In the Info window click the arrow next to “Open with”.
4. Click the pop-up menu, then choose Chrome.

Answer (score 31):

For Mac i'm using

```
open -a 'google chrome' /yourPath
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `-a` here?

Comment: It stands for application. Without this argument, the above command would look for a file called 'google chrome' in your working directory.

Answer (score 24):

From the **bash shell** *(on Windows)*, you can use:

`start myFilename.html`

and to open a folder:

`explorer "C:\Program Files\Git"`

*Added for reference, since my search landed here, too.*

Comment: Search landed me here also, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Bravo  8 years later and this still worked better than the answers above it.

Answer (score 10):

This solution has always worked for me -  `open -a "google\ chrome.app" index.html` - where "google\ chrome.app" is the name/location of chrome on your system.

OR

If Chrome is your default browser, simply - `open index.html`

Comment: open -a "google\ chrome.app" --args --arg1=value1 --arg2=value2

Answer (score 9):

If Chrome is your main browser, just use

```
see your_file.html
```

Answer (score 6):

You can open a file using below terminal commands 
    (Linux)

1. Open in New Tab  `google-chrome < filepath >`
2. Open in New Window  `google-chrome --new-window < filepath >`
3. Open in Incognito mode  `google-chrome --incognito (--incongnito-mode)  < filepath >`

```
<filepath> = localhost/test/../filename.html
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like Chrome is not in your $PATH the way it should be.  Easy solution would probably be to uninstall and reinstall Chrome, which should put it in your $PATH.  Then

```
google-chrome [file]
```

should work for you.

Comment: Your suggestion worked .

Answer (score 4):

For MacOS, with absolute path (if your Chrome is installed in the /Applications folder) in bash CLI use:

```
 /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

So, if you want to open the CNN webpage:

```
 /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome  www.cnn.com
```

Answer (score 3):

With Chrome *not* the default browser, this worked for me under Windows 10:

```
start "New Chrome Window Title" /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --new-window "file://C:/Folder/SubFolder/Sub Subfolder/thisfile.html"
```

You'll need:

- A way to convert the unqualified filename into a fully qualified filename;
- A way to convert backslashes to forward slashes;
- A way to prefix the "`file://`" onto the URL;
- To identify the specific directory in which you find `chrome.exe`;
- Decide on whether you want to keep the switch to force a new window;
- And other command line options as pertinent.

These should be reasonably doable in a `.bat` or `.cmd` file, using `FOR` commands and the text-replacing features of the `SET` command; or do all that in a `.vbs` or `.ps1` script which could be called from the batch file, etc.

But the basic syntax appears sound.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04, at least, it's `/opt/google/chrome/chrome`; I've also got a symlink to it at `/usr/bin/google-chrome`

Answer (score 2):

1. In bash or git CMD, make sure you are in your project directory/folder
2. Type `start index.html`
3. Hit Enter. Voila :-) you're done

This worked for me. Hope it does for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files index.html
```

Or

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files index.html
```

`--allow-file-access-from-files` will relax some [security settings](https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) , useful for testing with local files.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, the solution is to use:

```
google-chrome www.google.com
```

You can also use `--incognito` to open them in incognito mode:

```
google-chrome --incognito www.google.com
```

Note you can open multiple pages at the same time by just placing them one after the other:

```
google-chrome www.google.com www.yahoo.com
```

If you want to open them from a file, use the command substitution `$()` to open it and process on the fly:

```
google-chrome $(<file)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other things I saw worked for me, but I later found this that worked:

`explorer.exe index.html`

Comment: umm _explorer_ ??

Comment: It's what worked for me, it might because I had chrome set as my default browser, but not sure.

Comment: ok that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the location of chrome.exe on your system. If Chrome was installed into a default location, the Shell command in Windows looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Further, if you want to open a particular page in Chrome:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://google.com"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
start chrome "file or path"
```

same  for  FireFox

```
start firefox "file or path"
```

This worked for me.