# how do you open an html file in chrome web browser through ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've tried setting the BROWSER environment variable to the file location of "chrome.exe" which was "/mnt/c/Program File(x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" but I still get this error message when I try to run "see {filename}.html":

**Couldn't find a suitable web browser!
Set the BROWSER environment variable to your desired browser.
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1**

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: You cannot execute Windows binary from Linux.  You may find solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472464/how-do-i-open-a-file-with-chrome-from-the-command-line

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
export BROTWSER = YOURPATH
```

Actually Program File(x86) is kind wired.It seems that you are calling windows program through ubuntu, which is not possible. Try install chrome or chromium on ubuntu and just use:

```
chromium-browser filename.html
```