# is there a way to use the full file path in the command line without typing it?

Tags: pdf, command-line

For example, I want to open a PDF file in the browser from the command line (just because it's much faster and I need to open many files at once) and when I use the command `start [file name]` from its directory it try to open it as a executable, so I need to open the browser and type the full path of the file as an attribute, is there a way to call the full path without typing it?
what I exactly need is I need the full path of a file to convert it to string (for example in the browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open a file with Chrome from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472464/how-do-i-open-a-file-with-chrome-from-the-command-line)

Comment: The process should be the same for other browsers: either navigate to the location of the browser's executable or add that location to your environment, then start the browser with whichever command line flag that browser uses to allow the user to indicate a file should be opened when the process is started.

Comment: Are you trying to just open the file from command line (I'm assuming the browser is the associated program to open PDFs)? And are you in the folder where the file is? Or a parent folder? I have a potential solution, but I want to be sure it would answer your question appropriately.

Comment: @phentnil I'm in the folder where the file is, and when I start the browser (doesn't matter what browser...if you want to know: I've made an alias for ms edge. when I put a flag for it it sets it to the URL bar and I need to type the full path so the browser takes it as a string and opens it....is it clear enough? just need to find a way to use the full path because I need it as a string

Comment: @DM no, I've seen it, but his problem that the terminal can't understand the command that starts the browser, I can open it but my problem is I want a way to get the full path to give to the browser to convert it to a string to open it

Comment: Still not sure if I'm getting it. If you're saying that typing the full path would be cumbersome (I totally get that), then [using tab completions](https://www.howtogeek.com/195207/use-tab-completion-to-type-commands-faster-on-any-operating-system/) might be helpful. If your filename is `thisPDFisTotallyBananas.pdf` and you have another file `thisOtherPDFisNot.pdf` then you could type `thisP` then `TAB` to complete the filename without needing to type it all in.

Comment: @phentnil thanks! it makes it much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [tab completions](https://www.howtogeek.com/195207/use-tab-completion-to-type-commands-faster-on-any-operating-system/) may help. For example, if your target file is named `thisPDFisTotallyBananas.pdf` and you have another file in the same folder named `thisOtherPDFisNot.pdf`, you could type `thisP` then `TAB` to complete the file name in the command prompt without needing to type the whole filename.